# Clarification on Card Rulings on Exodia

Tags: yu-gi-oh

From the [Yugioh wiki](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Card_Rulings:Exodia_the_Forbidden_One), there are two rulings that contradict each other:

> Suppose that both players have "Appropriate" active, and that they are
> in the middle of a "loop" where both players keep drawing. If a player
> completes "Exodia the Forbidden One" during that loop, then he
> immediately wins the Duel and there is no more drawing.

> When resolving the effect of "Pot of Greed" or "Appropriate", if the
> only card left in your Deck is the last piece of "Exodia the Forbidden
> One", then you lose the Duel because you cannot draw when you are
> forced to draw.

Based on the 1st ruling, players can't lose by decking out once they've completed Exodia the Forbidden One, the 2nd one says otherwise.

Effectively, this boils down to the question: **Which has the higher priority, Card Draw Effects or Instant Win Effects?** Which ruling do I follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The specific case ruling overrides the general case ruling.

Each set of draws caused by Appropriate or Pot Of Greed is an atomic action. It must be completed in full before any further effects can occur.

Thus, while trapped in a loop where both players have Appropriate active, it is possible for the individual set of draws caused by one Appropriate to be complete, allowing the player who holds all five pieces of Exodia to win the game immediately (before the next set of draws is begun).

However, if the deck consists of only the fifth piece of Exodia, the set of draws must be completed. Since the deck is empty after the first draw and the player must still make a second draw, they lose the game through deck-out, despite holding a hand with all five pieces of Exodia.

Comment: So what happens in this scenario:

* Both players activate Appropriate
* Both already have 4 pieces in their hands.
* At some point one of the players (let's say Player 1) only has the last piece of Exodia in their deck left. 

Does Player 1 lose by decking out?

Comment: If they cannot draw a card when required, yes, they deck out. If they can complete Exodia between sets of required draws, no, they win immediately, the next set of draws does not occur.

Comment: So in the scenario I presented, if Player 1 had to draw because of Appropriate, then they lose. Okay, I understand, thank you.